# Two different projects with same package name

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an Android project with project name DemoMessageing, package name com.abc.xyz and added FCM to that project as created project in Firebase with package name com.abc.xyz for cloud messaging, applied SHA-1 and downloaded google-service.json. Put that .json in my app. I uploaded that project on Google Play also uploaded updates to the same.

Now i created new project in Firebase same package name com.abc.xyz but different project name as DemoMessageingTest. Removed the SHA-1 from old projectDemoMessageing) and applied same SHA-1 in new project(DemoMessageingTest) in Firebase. Download new google-service.json and place in my app.

Now i created signed apk and tried to upload on google play as a update for existing project. But google play is giving error as:

[image]

I increased the code version and again tried to upload the app on google play. But having same error.

My build.gradle is as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName "8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.whereismytransport.transportapisdk:transportapisdk:1.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':commonwidget')
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':panowidget')
    compile 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-7'
    compile project(':emojilib')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.5.jar')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.13'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.13'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.13'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am not able to understand what i am missing or what i am doing is right or not.

Please guide me with you suggestion and experience.

Comment: @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri I mentioned in question that i already tried what you suggest but getting same error.

Comment: Would you like to show your app level build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what the error is.

> You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 7

Your previous APK you uploaded with version code 7. If you keep the same package name, when you are uploading a new APK, you are sending an update to users. When an update happens, the version code must increase in your app. Increase your app version code (eg to 8), rebuild your APK, and the APK should upload fine.

Comment: My last uploaded version was 5. So i tried to make it 6 and then 7 but every time the error is same.